# How would i manipulate the layout of these buttons using an xml file

Tags: android, button, layout, appearance

I have created a grid of buttons which are currently showing as the default button from the tool box however i would like to manipulate attributes such as their size, shape and appearance how would i do that in a layout file? I am aware I would possibly use layoutinflater but I am not entirely sure how to use it

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
String[] buttonLabels = {"Button0", "Button1", "Button2", "Button3", "Button4", "Button5", "Button6", "Button7", "Button8"};
int[] rawMedia = {R.raw.sound0, R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3, R.raw.sound4, R.raw.sound5, R.raw.sound6, R.raw.sound7, R.raw.sound8};
public static final int ROWS = 3, COLUMNS = 3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.soundboard);

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(this);}








public void onClick(View view) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawMedia[view.getId()]);
    player.setLooping(false);
    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {player.release();} });
}

}
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? If you want to set those attributes in layout xml, those Views should be defined in the layout file. Are you asking how to translate your dynamic View creation to a layout xml file?

Comment: @Mike M. Yes I am aware they are set in a layout file apologies if I worder the question in correctly but yes I woul like to know how to translate it to an XML file

Comment: Well, there's some basic examples on the developer site, if that's what you're looking for: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html You'd just use Buttons instead of TextViews.

Comment: @MikeM. so ive made a new layout file (see in my code) and ive set it as content view yet it still doesnt use that layout what do i do now?

Comment: You need to remove the dynamic TableLayout creation, especially the `super.setContentView(layout);` line.

Comment: @MikeM. okay that seems to have solved the issue of showing the layout now how do i assign each button in the code to the ones in the layout

Comment: Check the following link to learn about the `id` attribute and the `findViewById()` method: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

Comment: No offense, but these are basic Android development concepts. If you haven't gone through the beginning documentation for developers on Android's developer's site, and some of the basic beginning tutorials and samples, then the advice I can give you is to do that before asking questions that you haven't researched. It is not a good use of your time, or others' time to do your research for you. You also might find it helpful to do some searching on Google on how to create an Android UI Layout in XML, and how to connect each layout element in the XML to corresponding objects in the code-behind.

Comment: @BryanHepburn no offense taken its a fair comment im just trying to submerse myself as best i can seems to be the best way of learning things. However you point is taken on board and i have figured the rest out myself

Comment: Dominic, you might also search YouTube, there's some pretty good tutorial videos out there on Android development.